Finding largest # in string
I have 2 columns of data - 1 with Equipment name, and another with the number of each equipment I have. The number of equipment is serialized as "SN01, SN02, SN03" and so on.
I need to create a formula where if I enter the "Equipment Name", it'll tell me the highest number - it cant be a count - since some numbers may have been skipped.

So - in the data above, if I enter "A" in the macro search, it should return 8, C should return 2, B should return 1.
I tried MaxIfs but that wasn't right. I also tried:
MaxSN = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("B:B"))
But that just gives the largest value in the column(as long as its numeric only).
Whats the best way to do this?

Ignoring leading zeroes, is the number always a 1 digit number? If yes, something like =MAX(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(B2:B10,1))) may work

Please, try the next VBA fast and compact. It uses a dictionary to keep the maximum number per equipment, iterates only once and returns at the end, starting from "D4":
Sub ExtractMaxPerEquipment()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As Object
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A
 
 arr = ws.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows
    dict(arr(i, 1)) = Application.Max(endNo(CStr(arr(i, 2))), dict(arr(i, 1))) 'load the dictionary
 Next i
 
 arrFin = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.keys, dict.Items)) 'combine the dictionary keys and items in an array
 
 ws.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value2 = arrFin 'drop the final array content in "D2"
End Sub

Function endNo(x As String) As String
    If x = "" Then endNo = 0: Exit Function
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "\d{1,5}?.*$"
        .Global = False
        endNo = .Execute(x)(0)
    End With
End Function

It deals with numeric part up to  5 digits. But it can be easily adapted to return more.
Please, send some feedback after testing it

Hi @faneduru - thank you! I love the approach - put the equipment and SN into an array, and then find the max. I dont need an output of highest # of all the items. I just need it for the next item - for example if I enter "C" in column A, it'll give me 10, or if I enter "D" (new equipment" In A, it'll give me 1?

I assume this line gets modified somehow:
ws.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value2 = arrFin

@Rick G But, the above code returns the highest number per Equipment Name. Isn't it what you need? Did you see its return? The line ws.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value2 = arrFin drops the array content starting from "D2". It can be adapted to return starting from any cell you need/want. Do you have something specific in mind when saying "this line gets modified somehow"? The code can be transformed in a function to return based on the supplied Equipment Name supplied as parameter...

Hi @FaneDuru - I didn't explain well I guess. In my sample data - I have 10 Equipment names listed - A through D in Column A. What I need to do is if I create a new entry in the 12th row -  a new equipment entry, I need the 2nd column to be populated with the next highest #. If I enter "A" in Column A, Row 12, it should give me 10 in Column B. If I enter "E" in Row 13, Column A, it should give me "1" (new equipment) in Column B.

@Rick G I am afraid I still cannot get you... Now, the maximum numeric value of "A" Equipment is 8. How to show it 10? Do you want saying 9, and did that by mistake? In such a case, if I understand that you need to increment by one the maximum existing value will it be a correct understanding? Then, the format of the numeric part is different, I mean (for A) "1", "02", "003". How to return the new incremented value? Like "9", "09" or 009? Besides that, do you want the corresponded incremented string ("SN009", for instance) to be written automatically in "B:B" column?

@Rick G Now, I could see your attempt for a new question which has been closed. In order to stay there ou need to paste a piece of code (you can paste my code from the answer) mentioning that you do not need it to return all unique Equipment serials, only the one input in A:A. It is necessary to use Worksheet_Change event. If you ask a new question and tag me here, I will try helping. If I will not be available, somebody else will solve the problem, I think. But be precise and also supply the Data. How to you like it to return? 9 Or **SN09" ("SN009") for inputting "A"?

What about the code behavior if you delete the Equipment description? Also, specify that new entries will be added only in the last empty cell of A:A (or not). When the string in A:A will be cleared, should the code also clear its correspondent in B:B?

Hi, I was looking at the spreadhseet that Siddhart had posted, and that's where I got the 10 from. But - yes - you're right - I need the next highest number only when the last empty cell in AA has a new equipment name added. In my original data - If I enter D in A12 (an empty field), it should give me SN003 in B12. If I enter a new equipment in A12 (say, F), it should give me SN001 in B12.

@Rick G Please, try posting a new question, showing my code and asking for automatically fill the B:B corresponding row with the maximum number of that equipment SN incremented with a unit. You also need to clarify the issues I tried mentioning in the above comments. If you tag me in some minutes I will be near my computer. If you do it later, I will try helping if I will be available. If not, having my code, somebody else will solve the problem, I think.

Formula Solution
You do not need VBA for this. A formula can help you.
=MAX(IF(A2:A11="A", IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B11), B2:B11, VALUE(MID(B2:B11, 3, LEN(B2:B11)-2)))))
Replace A in the formula with the relevant letter or simply point it to a cell which has the letter.

VBA Solution
Here is a function that you can use to get the largest number.
Option Explicit

Function GetLargestNumber(equipment As String, rng As Range) As Double
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim MaxNumber As Double
    Dim CurrentNumber As Double
    
    For Each aCell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        If aCell.Value = equipment Then
            If IsNumeric(aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2) Then
                CurrentNumber = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            ElseIf Left(aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2, 2) = "SN" Then
                CurrentNumber = Val(Mid(aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2, 3))
            End If
            If CurrentNumber > MaxNumber Then MaxNumber = CurrentNumber
        End If
    Next aCell
    
    GetLargestNumber = MaxNumber
End Function


Disclaimer: My answer assumes that the number will either start with "SN" or will just be a number.

I need a VBA solution as I need to auto-index that number by 1 when a new "Equipment" is added. Its not always 1 digit - it goes up to 2 (and 3, and maybe even 4) digits.

I had a feeling that you would need VBA. gimme few minutes. I am almost done

I have updated the above post with the VBA code. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Starting with just comparing a single string's values, which can be further modified to iterate over a range, I take the string as a byte and split it such that:
Function findLargestNumberInString(val As String)
    Dim comparisonValue As Long:  comparisonValue = 0
    Dim stringArray As Variant:  stringArray = Split(StrConv(val, vbUnicode), Chr(0))
    Dim i As Long:  For i = LBound(stringArray) To UBound(stringArray)
        If IsNumeric(stringArray(i)) = True Then
            If stringArray(i) > comparisonValue Then comparisonValue = stringArray(i)
        End If
    Next i
    findLargestNumberInString = comparisonValue
End Function

Function findLargestNumberInRange(identifier As String, srcData As Range)
    Dim cell As Range:  For Each cell In srcData
        Dim comparisonValue As Long:  comparisonValue = 0
        If cell.Offset(, -1) = identifier Then
            Dim val As Long:  val = findLargestNumberInString(cell.Value)
            If val > comparisonValue Then comparisonValue = val
        End If
    Next cell
    findLargestNumberInRange = comparisonValue
End Function

Sub tester()
    Debug.Print findLargestNumberInRange("a", Range("b1:b3"))
End Sub

This allows you to use the function either in excel or in other subroutines.

Edit1:
Added function to compare a range of cells, which is in addition to the first function.


My solution with a formula assuming that the number-containing text is no more than 10 characters long.
=MAX(IFERROR(--(MID(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11=D2),SEQUENCE(,10),10)),0))

D2 contains equipment name.
I don't understand why you need VBA. The formula is automatically recalculated. The ranges can be adjusted if necessary.

Here two functions, the first extract number from text and the second extract max number from range using the first function:
Public Function extractNumbers(Txt As String) As Double
    Dim re As Object, allMatches
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "([\d+\.]+)"
    re.Global = True
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(Txt)
    extractNumbers = IIf(allMatches.Count > 0, allMatches(0).Value, 0)
End Function

Public Function extractMaxNumber(CriteriaRng As Range, Criteria As String, CheckRng As Range) As Double
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim MaxNumber As Double
    Dim CurrentNumber As Double
    For Each aCell In CriteriaRng
        If aCell.Value = Criteria Then
            CurrentNumber = extractNumbers(Cells(aCell.Row, CheckRng.Column))
            If CurrentNumber > MaxNumber Then MaxNumber = CurrentNumber
        End If
    Next aCell
    extractMaxNumber = MaxNumber
End Function

test:

